# Is 'result' keyword broken in Drools DSL?

Tags: drools, dsl

I was working on some DSL examples in Drools and I required to 'see' how the generated DRL looked like. I've tried with both 6.3.0-SNAPSHOT and 6.4.0-SNAPSHOT versions.

According to the documentation [[1]](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html/ch08.html#d0e11247), it should be possible to add the special keyword `result` as a comment in the DSL file. This should print the generated DRL straight to System.out.

I've tried adding the following line to my DSL file, but I didn't get any DRL printed.

```
#/ debug display result and usage
```

I've also tried with:

```
#/ result
```

But I didn't have any luck.

So, my question is: Is this `result` keyword currently supported? The only keyword mentioned in the documentation that appears to be working is `usage`.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I've debugged the code myself and this appears to be a soft bug in Drools.
The thing is that the keywords `keyword`, `when` and `then` use System.out to print the debug statements, but the keywords `result` and `steps` are using a Logger.

Comment: IIRC, this may have been an intentional change done later - my original implementation of these debugging features was using stdout throughout.